# How to calculate the distance between the current date and another date in java

Tags: java

How to calculate the distance between the current date and another date in java @.@.it needs to be processed in 1 class. I'm newbie and search it but it has lots of errors. Thank you

Comment: You'll want to take some time (ha ha) looking over the [Date Time Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).  Java 8 introduced a new date/time API which should be used over all others.  You'll want to become farmilar with the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), which will allow you to calculate the amount of time between to `Temporal` points.  Of course, how you create those `Temporal` points is another question, but lets just say, if any answer you see isn't using the `java.time` API, it's out of date and ill advised

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities to check the difference between two dates regarding [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-difference):

with [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html):

```java
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime tenSecondsLater = now.plusSeconds(10);

long diff = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(now, tenSecondsLater);

assertEquals(10, diff);
```

with [`java.time.temporal.Temporal#until()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html#until(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)):

```java
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime tenSecondsLater = now.plusSeconds(10);

long diff = now.until(tenSecondsLater, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

assertEquals(10, diff);
```

with [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html):

```java
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime sixMinutesBehind = now.minusMinutes(6);

Duration duration = Duration.between(now, sixMinutesBehind);
long diff = Math.abs(duration.toMinutes());

assertEquals(6, diff);
```

with [`java.time.Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html):

```java
LocalDate aDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 9, 11);
LocalDate sixDaysBehind = aDate.minusDays(6);

Period period = Period.between(aDate, sixDaysBehind);
int diff = Math.abs(period.getDays());

assertEquals(6, diff);
```

You can also use any external library like [JodaTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or [Date4J](http://www.date4j.net/).

Comment: And can we drop the first example, it's like the worst thing you can do ever and should never be considered or used :P

Comment: I would like to list this only as an example. You can see that there are several other possibilities that can be used.

Comment: Yes, and I agree with all the other examples, but simple maths on date/time values is  very short sighted and naive (not having ago at you) and should never be considered as a "reasonable" method - especially when you've demonstrated all the others - there are so many "strange" rules around date/time handling :P

Comment: I added a short hint so that the first example is not recommended.

Comment: Ok, but I'd just avoid it - I get into to many arguments with junior devs and they said "but stackoverflow said...", which makes me cringe and lessons the value that SO has on the community - my opinion, take it with a grain of salt, but I'm extremely critical over date/time handling in IT, because in so many cases, it's not handled properly or well :P

Comment: Okay the criticism I understand and take the `java.util.date` out completely so that other junior developers do not use this code. :P.

Comment: với java.time.Duration:

LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime sixMinutesBehind = now.minusMinutes(6);

Duration duration = Duration.between(now, sixMinutesBehind);
long diff = Math.abs(duration.toMinutes());

assertEquals(6, diff);  
i don't know  but i has err . 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method assertEquals(int, long) is undefined for the type chan

Comment: The method `assertEquals` is part of [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) and is only used in tests, for example to compare values. In your logic you do not need to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

efficient way to find difference in days is by using ChronoUnit.DAYS

```
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;
long diff = DAYS.between(date1, date2);
```